# NextJS looses global vars from script on deep link / page refresh

Tags: next.js

In `Pages/_document.tsx` I have a script that loads some global public configuration like below.

The script just sets some global variable on the `window` object.

If I visit the home route of the app, the page loads everything is fine, but if I refresh the page on a nested route, (or deep link) it throws an error saying `ReferenceError: window is not defined`.

I'm guessing this is the server complaining, but I only need this config on the client, and I don't want to package the config vars up during build time, as I want to promote the built app down a pipeline and just update a few variables.  Is this the right approach?

```js
  import Script from 'next/script'
   ...
   ...
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang='en'>
        <Head>
          <meta charSet='UTF-8' />
          <meta httpEquiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
          <Script src='/scripts/public-config.js' strategy='beforeInteractive' />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a better way, but I ended up checking if `window` exists anywhere I use it, so in my `public-config.js` file I did this:

```js
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  window.MY_PUBLIC_CONFIG = {
    MY_VAR: 'HELLO WORLD'
  }
}
```

and anywhere referencing it needs to do the same:

```js
export const config = (typeof window !== 'undefined')
  ? window.MY_PUBLIC_CONFIG
  : {}
```